# preselected option in struts2 (freemarker)

Tags: forms, select, struts2, tags, freemarker

I cannot make my freemarker struts2 select tag to show the default value for the object related list of options.

In my action I have:

```
private List<CodeLabel> modifRoomTypeOpt;
```

inside I have objects CodeLabel with values like S:Single, D:Double,...

```
<@s.select id="123123"
  name="roomModif[2].type"
  value="${modifiedRoom.type}"
  list="modifRoomTypeOpt" listKey="code" listValue="label"/>
```

In the generated html, i can see options with values S,D,T,... and labels Single, Double,...  so iteration over my CodeLabel object was done. But in my select, 1st option is always preselected. I checked value of ${modifiedRoom.type} and its 'D'.
Why option with value D is not preselected?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting,

I did a bit of investigation and code-debugging and I discovered that the *value* attribute is evaluated as an OGNL variable. It means that Struts2 looks into the stack for a variable matching the string you put in the *value* attribute.

Internally the evaluated result then is put into the list of attributes as *nameValue*.

So I surprisingly found that using the attribute *nameValue* instead of *value* is a good workaround to have a select element preselected with a given value.

In your case:

```
<@s.select id="123123"
name="roomModif[2].type"
nameValue="${modifiedRoom.type}"
list="modifRoomTypeOpt" listKey="code" listValue="label"/>
```

or also:

```
<@s.select id="123123"
name="roomModif[2].type"
nameValue=modifiedRoom.type
list="modifRoomTypeOpt" listKey="code" listValue="label"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the default value you need to set the value attribute of the select tag for instance:

```
<@s.select id="123123"
name="roomModif[2].type"
value="${modifiedRoom.type}"
list="modifRoomTypeOpt" listKey="code" listValue="label"
value="modifRoomTypeOpt.get(1)"   />
```

The code has not been tested, but I believe it should work.
For reference use http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/select.html

If you want to set a default header on the select element use the headerKey and headerValue attributes.